# How to calculate columns based on other columns codes in hive

Tags: if-statement, hive, group-by, sum

[image]

We have a sale table with different sale amount and sale code. I want to calculate the sale total amount base on different code.

The formula is Total sale = code1 -code2 +code3 -code 4.

How can I get the result by a hive query?

Comment: Can't you just `SUM` the `Amount` and `GROUP BY` then `ID`?

Comment: The formula is code1 -code2 +code3 -code 4 and I am not able just to sum the amount and group by them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with conditional aggregation (assuming there is one row per ID per Code).

```
select id 
      ,coalesce(max(case when code = 'code1' then cast(amount as int) end), 0) -
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code2' then cast(amount as int) end), 0) +
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code3' then cast(amount as int) end), 0) -
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code4' then cast(amount as int) end), 0) 
from tbl
group by id
```

Comment: Hi Vamsi, the amount is varchar(255). I get the following error message

Argument type mismatch '0': The expressions after COALESCE should all have the same type: "varchar(255)" is expected but "int" is found (state=42000,code=10016)

Comment: check the edit..`cast`ing the amount to `int`..modify it as necessary.

Comment: select id 
      ,coalesce(max(case when code = 'code1' then cast (amount as int) end), 0) -
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code2' then cast (amount as int) end), 0) +
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code3' then cast (amount as int) end), 0) -
       coalesce(max(case when code = 'code4' then cast (amount as int) end), 0) 
from tbl
group by id